# ARM Template for Azure Custom Connector using On-Premises Data Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I am trying to make an ARM Template for a Custom Connector which needs to have enabled the use of on-premises Data Gateway. I am getting everything right except this last requirement, since I create a fully configured Custom Connector, except for the fact that the check-mark for using the on-premises Data Gateway is not active.

Any idea which setting/element I need to add change to get this done?

This is my template up to now:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/customApis",
    "name": "[parameters('Connection_Name')]",
    "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
    "location": "centralus",
    "scale": null,
    "properties": {
        "connectionParameters": {
            "authType": {
                "type": "string",
                "allowedValues": [
                    {
                        "value": "none"
                    }
                ],
                "uiDefinition": {
                    "displayName": "Authentication Type",
                    "description": "Authentication type to connect to your API",
                    "tooltip": "Authentication type to connect to your API",
                    "constraints": {
                        "tabIndex": 1,
                        "required": "true",
                        "allowedValues": [
                            {
                                "text": "none",
                                "value": "anonymous"
                            }
                        ],
                        "capability": [
                            "gateway"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "gateway": {
                "type": "gatewaySetting",
                "gatewaySettings": {
                    "dataSourceType": "CustomConnector",
                    "connectionDetails": []
                },
                "uiDefinition": {
                    "constraints": {
                        "tabIndex": 4,
                        "required": "true",
                        "capability": [
                            "gateway"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "backendService": {
          "serviceUrl": "[parameters('ServiceUrl')]"
        },
        "apiType": "Soap",
        "wsdlDefinition": {
          "importMethod": "SoapPassThrough"
        },          
        "swagger": {
          "swagger": "2.0",
          "info": {
            "title": "SOAP pass-through",
            "description": "Custom Connector for SOAP Operation",
            "version": "1.0"
          },
          "host": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "basePath": "/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx",
          "consumes": [],
          "produces": [],
          "paths": {
            "/": {
              "post": {
                "responses": {
                  "default": {
                    "description": "default",
                    "schema": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "title": "",
                      "x-ms-visibility": "important"
                    },
                    "headers": {
                      "Content-Type": {
                        "description": "Content-Type",
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "summary": "GetOrigins",
                "description": "GetOrigins",
                "operationId": "GetOrigins",
                "parameters": [
                  {
                    "name": "Content-Type",
                    "in": "header",
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "body",
                    "in": "body",
                    "required": false,
                    "schema": {
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "definitions": {},
          "parameters": {},
          "responses": {},
          "securityDefinitions": {},
          "security": [],
          "tags": [],
          "schemes": [
            "http"
          ]
        },          
        "description": "[concat('Custom Connector for SOAP', parameters('Connection_Name'),' Operation')]",
        "displayName": "[parameters('Connection_Name')]",
        "iconUri": "/Content/retail/assets/default-connection-icon.6296199fc1d74aa45ca68e1253762025.2.svg"
    },      
    "dependsOn": []
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To enable the 'On-Premises Data Gateway' option, you need to add gateway to the capabilities array like so:

```
"properties" {        
    "capabilities": [
        "gateway"
    ],

}
```

Comment: I'm working on a customer connector ARM template right now and can confirm that this solution works and should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

the On-Premises Data Gateway option is not available from ARM templates, you must to install your template and manually add the check box from the Azure portal.

Thanks.